# Rack-Mini-Profiler analyze-memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, rack-mini-profiler

I  analyze the memory of my app with rack-mini-profilers:

`?pp=analyze-memory`

At the very first beginning of my analyzation I find this section:

Total allocated: 11701453 bytes (143079 objects)
Total retained:  1380491 bytes (15087 objects)

```
allocated memory by gem
-----------------------------------
   1959594  sprockets-3.7.1
   1520426  activesupport-5.0.2
   1324106  other
   1120203  bson-4.2.1
   1111010  scout_apm-3.0.0.pre9
   1030375  actionview-5.0.2
    781675  2.4.1/lib
    583067  gn2016/app
    495216  mongoid-6.1.0
    380060  actionpack-5.0.2
    375379  erubis-2.7.0
    370934  mongo-2.4.1
    174568  i18n-0.8.1
     72385  webrat-0.7.3
     57638  cancancan-1.16.0
     45136  countries-7404f9774051
     40912  dalli-2.7.6
     33412  nokogiri-1.7.1

1000 Largest strings:

.select2-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
 # and all of my CSS comes here
 .......
 ......
 ..... 
 .... 
 ... 
 ..
 .
```

It lists the whole select2 CSS file followed 
by the whole bootstrap CSS and so on...

in my application.scss I have this:

```
/*
 *
 *= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap
*/
@import 'font-awesome';
@import 'custom';
```

Is this normal behaviour that the CSS is in memory as a string?
Is this a misconfiguration?

I am searching for a memory leak in my app and thought that this could be a starting point to look at.

Comment: Is this in Dev mode ?

Comment: yes, ``Rails.env=development``

Comment: Then this is an  expected behavior, this is for asset manipulation